# Error mounting /dev/loop0 at /media/root/disk

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, after a power cut-off shutdown, the system will show an error message when it started:
[image]

I didn't mount the /dev/loop0 file. I checked the /media/root folder, it doesn't contain the disk folder. I can close this message, and the system works well.

How to solve this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same situation after modify /etc/fstab still happend

/dev/loop0~9 are loop devices

use command [losetup] to check those devices

1.stop server-
sudo systemctl disable snapd.service

or

2.clean it-
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd

after do this and reboot will be ok